# How to search and jump to tag without going to window of tagbar?

Tags: tags, plugin-tagbar

I have tagbar installed and for javascript files I'm using jsctags to generate tags. It's working perfectly.

I can use `<Enter>` in tagbar to jump to a tag. But what I want is an ex command to search tags with a pattern. If it's found, then it should jump to it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim comes with a complete set of commands and options for using tags. You can read all about it in `:help tags` (the generic stuff) and `:help ctags` (the ctags-specific stuff that also applies to jsctags).

But your plugin doesn't use any of those commands and settings and don't even use an actual `tags` file so you have an hyper-specialized plugin *and* a built-in mechanism that work in largely overlapping silos. This means that you have to learn two different systems instead of just one.

My advice (as a "senior" front end developer and as an experienced vimmer) is to not use that plugin and rely entirely on built-in features. This will make your life a lot easier and your coding faster.